# SQLAlchemy ORM check if column is a foreign_key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hi I was wondering if anyone knows of the most efficient way to find out if a column has a foreignKey relationship or not.

```python
class StudentIntendCourse(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'studentIntendCourse'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    studentID = Column('studentID',Integer,ForeignKey('student.id'))
    courseID = Column('courseID',Integer,ForeignKey('course.id'))
    course = relationship("Course",backref="studentIntendedCourses")
```

I would like to find out if is_foreign_key(StudentIntendCourse.studentID)?

Answer (score 5):

The `ForeignKey` objects associated with an individual `Column` object are available in the [*foreign_keys*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.foreign_keys) collection of that column.

```
foreign_keys_set = StudentIntendCourse.__table__.c.studentID.foreign_keys
```

You can check if this set is non empty

Comment: Why not simply "foreign_keys_set = StudentIntendCourse.studentID.foreign_keys"?

Answer (score 2):

All columns have the attribute 'foreign_keys', that is a set, but it is empty for all column that are not ForeignKey, so a simple test can give you the correct answer. In your example:

```
def is_foreign_key(column):
    return True if column.foreign_keys else False

print(is_foreign_key(StudentIntendCourse.studentID))
```

If you want to have  list of all ForeignKey:

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

foreign_keys_list = [c.key for c in inspect(StudentIntendCourse) if getattr(StudentIntendCourse, c.key).foreign_keys]
```

I strongly suggest to use [inspection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/inspection.html), instead, directly access the nested structures of SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 2):

*Old answer*:

I solved this by using the [sqlalchemy.orm.Mapper.relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Mapper.relationships) !, Property of inspect

```py
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

foreign_keys = [c.key for c in inspect(model).relationships]
```

*Update* :
This might be useful for anyone in future the [sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_foreign_keys), implements alot of useful methods for this matter.

You can do something like this to test if a column if a foreign key.

```py
def is_foreign_key(engine,table_name,foreign_key_column,schema):

   list_of_foreign_keys = inspect(engine).get_foreign_keys(table_name=table_name,schema=schema)

   list_of_bool = [True for elem in list_of_foreign_keys if 
   foreign_key_column in elem.get("referred_columns")]

   return any(list_of_bool)
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Actually I didn't have the table object, but the table name, and similarly the column name. Here is my solution:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine( URL )
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)

def is_foreign_key(table_name, col_name):
    return col_name in [e.target_fullname for e in meta.tables[table_name].foreign_keys]
```

NOTE:

```
meta.tables[table_name].foreign_keys == Table.__table__.foreign_keys
```